# Better syntax for assigning a same-name value to object key (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I got this situation

```
const name = 'David'

const person = {
  name : ''
}
```

If I want to assign the `name` *variable* into the `name` *key* inside `person` ,
I'd do something like that:

```
person.name = name
```

But is there a cleaner way to do so?

without repeating `name`

Comment: `Object.assign(person, { name })` ?

Comment: Since the local variable name should be independent from the object's property name, there is nothing wrong with writing it twice.